# Al usar el comando select en r me arroja el error: "unused error"

Tags: r

Cargue unas librerias necesarias para manejar los datos que tengo (un archivo csv de 42 columnas y cerca de 200000 filas)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fitdistrplus)
library(MASS)
library(survival)
```

Cree un dataframe (d41) para poder trabajar mis datos (funciona esta linea)

```
d41 = read.table("2014_1.csv",sep=";",header=T)
```

Pero aquí, al correr estos comandos (CONCENTRACION_PORCENTAJE_CO2 y POTENCIA_BRUTA_MWH son las columnas con las que necesito trabajar), al ejecutar el select me arroja el siguiente error:

> Error in select(., CONCENTRACION_PORCENTAJE_CO2, POTENCIA_BRUTA_MWH) :
>   unused arguments (CONCENTRACION_PORCENTAJE_CO2, POTENCIA_BRUTA_MWH)

```
d41_n= d41 %>%
    select(CONCENTRACION_PORCENTAJE_CO2, POTENCIA_BRUTA_MWH) %>%
    filter(CONCENTRACION_PORCENTAJE_CO2 != NA , POTENCIA_BRUTA_MWH != NA)
```

Y la verdad es que he intentado todo y siempre me tira este error, porfa, no entiendo que hago mal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se debe básicamente a que el paquete `MASS` incorpora una función `select()` que por el orden de carga "enmascara" el `select()` de  `dplyr/tidyverse`. De hecho, seguramente tienes un `warning` al cargar los paquetes que dice algo así:

> Attaching package: ‘MASS’
>
> The following object is masked from ‘package:dplyr’:
>
> ```
> select
> ```

Posibles soluciones:

1. Ser más explícito al invocar `select()`indicando el paquete:

   ```
   d41_n <- d41 %>%
       dplyr::select(CONCENTRACION_PORCENTAJE_CO2, POTENCIA_BRUTA_MWH)
   ```
2. Si no vas a usar la función `select()` del paquete `MASS`, puede modificar el orden de carga, para que `tidyverse` se cargue luego de `MASS`:

   ```
   library(fitdistrplus)
   library(MASS)
   library(survival)
   library(tidyverse)
   ```

Comment: Estimado, no sabe cuanto se lo agradezco, funciono perfecto, nadie me había propuesto eso antes, de verdad mil gracias

Comment: @VichoDániel dado que la respuesta te ha solucionado el problema recuerda marcar la solución de Patricio como aceptada, para que si otro usuario en el futuro tiene el mismo problema sepa que ésta ha sido la que funcionó. Además así se lo agradeces con puntos.

Comment: Perfecto, no sabía, gracias David