# Por qué falla mi group_by?

Tags: r, group-by

Primero que nada, saludos.

Tengo problemas al usar el group_by(). Quizá no lo estoy entendiendo bien.

Tengo el siguiente data frame:

```
a<-sample(c("A","B","C","D"), size = 500, replace = T)
b<-sample(1:200, size = 500, replace = T)

df<-data.frame(a,b)
```

Y quiero agrupar por el vector a y que me resulte la media del vector b,  utilizo el siguiente comando:

```
df %>%
  group_by(a)  %>%
  summarise(red=mean(b))
```

Pero me sale lo siguiente:

```
    red
1 99.3
```

No esperaba ese resultado. Lo que deseo es lo siguiente:

```
  a         b
1 A 100.69173
2 B  91.00725
3 C 106.75962
4 D  94.48800
```

Por favor, ayuda.

En que me estoy equivocando.

**Gracias de antemano.**

Me sale esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por empezar, revisemos si tienes algún conflicto de nombre con esto: `c("group_by", "summarise", "mean") %in% conflicts()`  si obtienes algún `TRUE` hay una redefinición de estas funciones

Comment: Resulta verdadero en la función `summarise`

Comment: Tienes un conflicto con `summarise`, hay otro `summarise` de otro paquete que está enmascarando esta función, puedes resolver este conflicto o simplemente anteponer el paquete con `dplyr::summarise(red=mean(b))`

Comment: Para más info: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/304145/al-usar-el-comando-select-en-r-me-arroja-el-error-unused-error/304154#304154

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!!  Es de gran ayuda!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

a mi si me funcionó

```
> a<-sample(c("A","B","C","D"), size = 500, replace = T)
> b<-sample(1:200, size = 500, replace = T)
> df<-data.frame(a,b)
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% group_by(a)  %>%  summarise(red=mean(b))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  a       red
  <fct> <dbl>
1 A     101. 
2 B      99.2
3 C     110. 
4 D     103.
```

debe ser porque no cargaste la libreria dplyr

Comment: Si cargué por eso corre. Si no hubiese cargado me hubiese aparecido que la función group_by no se encuentra. 

El problema radicaba en el conflicto de funciones.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando tengas librerías que tenga un conflicto de funciones puedes usar `::`, antecedido de la librería, con eso le indicas a R específicamente la librería a la que haces referencia.

De esta manera puedes hacer:

```
df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(a)  %>%
  dplyr::summarise(red=mean(b))
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente _qué hace_ `::`: lee [answer].